# How can I render dynamic components in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-dynamic-components

I have a multidimensional array of components I want to render to a grid:

```
[
  [
    {
      component: class TitleComponent,
      data: {
        title: "Invoice"
      },
      row: 1
    },
    {
      component: class AddressComponent,
      data: {
        companyName: "Comapny Name",
        addressLineOne: "123 Street Name",
        addressLineTwo: "Area",
        addressLineThree: "City"
      },
      row: 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      component: class DetailsComponent,
      data: {
        description: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
      },
      row: 2
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to render the component in the required row, for example, the `TitleComponent` should be rendered in the first row, while the `DetailsComponent` should be rendered in the second row.

The html structure I am looking to output is something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <div *ngFor="let component of row">
    <ng-template gridBlock></ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure how possible the output is, but essentially I want to create a row for each array and then render each component inside the relevant row.

I have used `@ViewChildren` to render the components, but seems like whenever I add a new dynamic component to the `Querylist`, it messes up the order in which the components are rendered.

```
@ViewChildren( GridContainerDirective ) components!: QueryList< GridContainerDirective >
```

P.S. I am new to angular and any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://indepth.dev/posts/1400/components-by-selector-name-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render components with the help of `*ngComponentOutlet` directive

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <div *ngFor="let component of row">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component.component"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

however it is not possible to pass data directly. so it would be required to craete injectors for those components, and inject the data inside of them